# Access query combo box source based on individual record

Tags: ms-access, filter, drop-down-menu, dropdown

my database has MachineT, ProductT and ProductionT.
each product can be made only in some specific machines (multivalue field).
when planning production I need the dropdown menu to show only the possible machines for that product in a form containing a datasheet view.

In the actual database the ProductionF has a data picker and the subform is based on ProductionQ only for that day and it is important to keep the datasheet view because the planner is adding dozens of records in one sitting.
thank you

*edit - I tried to force the field in ProductionT via lookup but it does not filter for each record.
[image: picture showing issue]

Answer (score 1):

[If you only have 4 machines], what if in ProductT, rather than just one Machine ID, you have fields M1,M2,M3,M4 as a Yes/No (checkbox) selection, then you can make your combo box where fields = True
or maybe this link can help you http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

**Edit**
What if you have a new table called something like "Product_machine_combo" and this is where you can combine the relationship between the product and the machine used. You could use a list box that lists the Products and have a  `ListBox` for the machines (kind of shown below; link to this resource: https://www.iaccessworld.com/add-items-textbox-listbox/). I just don't know how it would show up in the table. Or you could add a list box to the product form itself?

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the thought, but I have several machines and more being added, others being disposed of, so this would mean adding new columns and rewriting the formulas to adapt. the example picture is a rewrite of the actual program which has many more intricacies that were not relevant to my question, this is why it is so simple. thank you

Comment: I edited my answer to show another suggestion; let me know if this helps any!